# Can I enroll in Apple's Developer Program from Kuwait?

Tags: developer-program

How can I enroll in Apple's Developer Program from Kuwait?

I am from Kuwait. I have Apple IDs associated with the USA and associated with my country of origin. When I try to enroll with my Kuwait based account, I keep getting an error saying:

> Sorry, you can’t enroll at this time.
>
> [image: apple.com screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Are you trying to enroll as an individual or organization?

Comment: im trying to enroll as an individual

Comment: Are you of legal age to enroll (18 years or older in most jurisdictions)?

Comment: im 18 years old

Comment: Can you please recheck your date of birth on file by going to https://appleid.apple.com/ ? This error is generally caused when a minor tries to enroll into developer program.

Comment: wen I use my us account I can enroll but once I try with my country I get an error im from Kuwait

Comment: Please elaborate on this point: `wen I use my us account I can enroll but once I try with my country i get an error `. Consider including appropriate screenshots.

Comment: wen I use USA country on the account I can enroll but when I none USA account  like Kuwait I got error

Comment: Related but not duplicate questions https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164009 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151037

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can’t join if Apple doesn’t offer a store and that SKU in your place of legal residence.

You’d likely want to consult a lawyer familiar with the implications setting up a new legal residence elsewhere or form a company with a legal presence / residence elsewhere. This is more of a bureaucratic / [taxation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151037/is-it-possible-to-buy-an-ios-developer-program-for-an-ibc-that-was-formed-in-bel) / legal problem than a technical one.

- [Purchase Apple Developer Program outside of USA](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199082/purchase-apple-developer-program-outside-of-usa)
- [Which countries can an individual iOS developer reside in in order to receive payments from Apple?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164009/which-countries-can-an-individual-ios-developer-reside-in-in-order-to-receive-pa/)

At a high level, you don’t get the enter into an NDA to accept confidential builds from apple and you don’t get to list on the stores and get paid when you’re not from the countries where Apple is set up today. You can start building and installing apps yourself, though without needing a dev account.

Comment: And when I say set up a company, I do not mean a [trivial shell corporation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190861/cannot-enroll-in-apple-developer-program) but legitimately choosing a place and team to do business.

Comment: can I buy it with us account

Comment: @Hamany Not unless you have a US presence and can enter a contract with a US address.

Comment: I found out you can but I can not enroll because im 18 I can enroll with my own country when i turn 21

Comment: in the US (18-Year-old or older ) in Kuwait (21-Year-old or older)